# Определение класса без реализации

Tags: c++

Что означает такая запись: class MyClass; ? объявление существующего класса без реализации

Comment: @ar-hovsepyan, что вы имеете под фразой << Если вы не выполните обещание, компилятор потребует сделать это>> ?

Comment: @ar-hovsepyan, можно ссылку на статью?

Comment: @ar-hovsepyan, кажется я нашёл. Это называется декларация класса.

Comment: Это просто синоним  выражения  " обьявление  класса".  Не понятно что вас интересует_ слово или понятие?... По сему удаляю все мои комментарии...

Comment: @ar-hovsepyan, я использую указатели на классах в других классах. Без декларации класса, на который я хочу создать указатель, компилятор отказывается компилировать проект

Answer (score 5):

Для компилятора это знак того, что класс полностью объявлен в другом месте этого проекта (например, в соседнем файле).

Так делают, чтобы избежать взаимного включения. Например, у Вас есть файл `X.h` в котором объявлен класс `X` и файл `Y.h`, в котором объявлен класс `Y`. При этом Вам зачем-то понадобилось использовать класс `X` в классе `Y` и наоборот (например, объекты одного класса являются свойствами другого). Тогда, если включить один файл в другой с помощью `#include`, и со вторым сделать то же самое, компилятор засыплет Вас ошибками, вызванными взаимным включением. И вот именно в такой ситуации используют представленное Вами объявление. Например в классе `X`, чтобы объявить свойство, являющееся объектом класса `Y`, можно не писать `#include"Y.h"`, а написать лишь `class Y;`. Это даст понять компилятору, что класс `Y` объявлен где-то вне этого файла, и при сборке он обязательно его найдёт.

Возможно это не единственный пример использования такой конструкции. Я просто рассказал то, с чем сам сталкивался на практике.

Comment: Не обязательно в другом файле, просто в другом месте. Ну или вообще не определён, что тоже может быть.

Comment: @ixSci Согласен.